# Is it possible to massively approve reported posts in a Facebook group?

Tags: facebook-groups

Suddenly from one day to the other almost 2,000 reported posts appeared in my Facebook group. They are shown as if they were reported by common people and not by Facebook, but the names of the ones who reported them dont appear, and the posts have nothing wrong, what makes me think it's a Facebook bug something wrong in the algorithm that detects TOS violation posts and something wrong by placing them as if they were reported by people and not Facebook.

So I need to massively approve all those posts, is there any way to do it?